# how to implement visibility on javascript with incremental + option (or visibility)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want an incremental **+** option in my script eg. one by one expansion.

Suppose after click on Optiontional Configurations **+** than Network Config will be expand with another **+** option, now if I want another input than I will click on **+** and **Neighbor Config** will be expand.

Please help me no this, I am new on javascript, thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<h>OPSF Configuration</h>
</br>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function defaultconf() {
            var nodes = document.getElementById("d1").getElementsByTagName('*');
            for(var k = 0; k < nodes.length; k++)
            {
                nodes[k].style.visibility ="hidden";
            }
        }

        function options1() {
            var str = arguments[0];
            var nodes = document.getElementById(str).getElementsByTagName('input');
            for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
            {
                nodes[i].style.visibility ="hidden";
            }
            var nodes = document.getElementById(str).getElementsByTagName('button');
            var name = document.getElementById(str).getElementsByTagName('label');
            for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
            {
                if (nodes[i].style.visibility == "hidden" || name[i].style.visibility == "hidden")
                {
                    nodes[i].style.visibility ="visible";
                    name[i].style.visibility ="visible";
                }
                else
                {
                    nodes[i].style.visibility ="hidden";
                    name[i].style.visibility ="hidden";
                }
            }

        }

        function options() {
            var str = arguments[0];
            var nodes = document.getElementById(str).getElementsByTagName('*');
            for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
            {
                if (nodes[i].style.visibility == "hidden")
                    nodes[i].style.visibility = "visible";
                else
                    nodes[i].style.visibility ="hidden";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<body onload="defaultconf()">
<br/>
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="options('d1')">Optiontional Configurations </td></tr>
<div id="d1">
    <table>
        <br/>
        <tr><td>
                <input type="button" value="+" onclick="options('network')">Network Config
                <div id="network">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style11" valign=top style="height: 4px">Network</td>
                            <td class="style9" style="height: 4px">
                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $network?>" name="network" size="2" style="width: 147px">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td></tr>



            <tr><td>
                <br/>
                <input type="button" value="+" onclick="options('neighbor')">Neighbor Config
                <div id="neighbor">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style11" valign=top style="height: 4px">Neighbor IP</td>
                            <td class="style9" style="height: 4px">
                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $neighbor?>" name="neighbor" size="2" style="width: 147px">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

        </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong with your current script ? if possible could you create a jsfiddle and replicate your issue there.http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: In my script input option expansion is all together.. I want incremental... one by one...

Comment: can you post `style.css` here

Comment: <style type="text/css">
.style1 {
        font-family: Calibri;
}
.style4 {
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: bold;
}
.style5 {
        text-align: right;
}
.style6 {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        margin-right: 0px;
        }
.newStyle1 {
        border-style: groove;
        border-width: thin;
}
.style8 {
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

Comment: .style9 {
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-family: Calibri;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
.style11 {
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
.style12 {
        color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style13 {
        font-weight: bold;
                background-color: #007ABB;
        color: #C0C0C0;
}

Comment: .style15 {
        color: #C0C0C0;
}
.style16 {
        text-align: left;
}
.style17 {
        font-family: Calibri;
        text-align: right;
}
</style>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rajnaiknitrr/v7rtjb7n/1/

Comment: Since you have tagged jquery, it is easy to implement in jquery. https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/uaasqbmy/3/

Comment: Thanks so much... On your above provided code I wanted to expansion in hierarchical manner. Eg: first on clicking the + (Optional Configurations) **Network Config** will come with 1 more **+** option, again on clicking **+** one more expansion box will open with **Neighbor Config** and so on...

Please help me on this... thanks again in advance :-) and thanks so much for your valuable time....

Comment: i have created a basic example , but as your requirement grows you need to tweak the code, https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/uaasqbmy/4/

Comment: working fine... so much thanks

Comment: cool i`ll post  this as answer in a while, you can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution in jquery would be to use `.toggle()` to toggle the sub-views.

Also I have updated the DOM structure.

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(function() {
   var siblingCounter = 0;
   $('.sub-view').hide();
   $('.main-view').on('click', function() {
      var localCounter = $(this).hasClass('default') ? siblingCounter++ : 0;
      $(this).siblings('.sub-view').eq(localCounter).toggle();
   });
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/uaasqbmy/4/)

*Note:*

- If you are using `jQuery` library then avoid writing code in vanilla javascript unless you need something which is not available in jQuery **[I personally havent come across so far ]**.
- Use a `class` selector for applying generic/common css styles rather than creating seperate `id` selector styles. basically this will prevent redundant css styles across multiple rule-set

Comment: @Raj: your welcome,now you can close this question by ticking the above solution as answer. happy coding :)